# Mais de um valor em um mesmo parâmetro GET

Tags: php, html, get

É possível atribuir mais de um valor em um mesmo parâmetro GET via http, como se eu tivesse passando um array nesse parametro?

Por exemplo: http://www.exemplo.com/buscar?campos=nome,data,endereco

Edit1: A aplicação que receberá a requisição é desenvolvida em Laravel, caso isso influencie.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3061292

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, é possível passar dessa forma, podes usar o [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php) depois para obter cada valor individualmente.

```
$campos = explode(",", $_GET["campos"]);
```

Também podes passar como array

```
// ?campos[]=nome&campos[]=data&campos[]=endereco
$campos = $_GET["campos"]; // já vai ser um array
```

Answer (score 2):

É possível sim, basta colocar `[]` depois do nome do parâmetro, assim ele montará automaticamente o `array`, os parâmetros ficariam assim:

> ?campos[]=nome&campos[]=data&campos[]=endereço

Ao fazer um `var_dump($_GET)`, o retorno será:

> array(1) { ["campos"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(4) "nome" [1]=>
>   string(4) "data" [2]=> string(9) "endereço" } }